# Can Amazon Kinesis be accessed from outside AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache-kafka, amazon-kinesis

I am having a first look at Amazon Kinesis to compare it to Apache Kafka.

Can Kinesis Producers/Consumers access the Kinesis broker from outside AWS? Or have the (Java) clients to be deployed on a EC2 instance?

Comment: By the way, you can  use Kafka Connect to stream topics between Kafka and Kinesis

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you can create and interact with your streams using the [API](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/kinesis/latest/APIReference/Welcome.html) and the AWS SDKs.